# Is there anyway to get the USB Mac Address of the iPhone device?

Tags: ios, macos, networking, mac-address

Not the WiFi or Bluetooth one. I was doing the internet sharing via reverse tethering to the device via USB, the iPhone should have a Mac Address specific to that interface.

I've checked `ideviceinfo` and that only provide me the Mac Address of WiFi and Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you will find a MAC address of the USB interface when tethering to your computer. That is, USB interfaces do not have MAC addresses to begin with. Further, the computer does not connect to the phone via USB the same way it would connect via wifi, or connect to a switch. When the iPhone is connected to the computer via USB, it is like adding a new NIC to the computer, so effectively the MAC address on your computer will be the only MAC address you see between your phone and your computer. The wifi, cellular, or bluetooth MAC addresses will be used by your phone to connect to the "external" network, however your computer's MAC address will not be seen on those networks as your phone will perform NAT functions between the "external" network and your computer.

Comment: Hi Duke, thanks for the reply! I've ran `arp -a -i bridge100` on two different macbooks with the same iPhone device plugged in, and they were showing me the same mac address, so I assume there must be some mac address hidden in my iPhone that is not normally exposed to the users.